# laravel 5.3 - display json data from mysql text field in blade template

Tags: php, json, notifications, laravel-blade, laravel-5.3

I have this data in a mysql `text` field:

```
{"message":"New comment from pp on one of your photos.","action":"\/photos\/9372"}
```

It is written into the database with this function (laravel notification):

```
public function toArray($notifiable)
{
    return [
        'message' => 'New comment from '.Auth::user()->username.' on one of your photos.',
        'action' => '/photos/'.$this->comment->photo_id
    ];
}
```

The [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/notifications#database-notifications) says:

```
"The returned array will be encoded as JSON and stored in the data column of your notifications table."
```

Then I fetch the data like this:

```
$notifications = Auth::user()->notifications()->paginate(30);

return view('home.index')->with('notifications',$notifications);
```

How can I display the contents of this `json` `array` (?) in a blade view? I can `var_dump()` it but not display. It is always `undefinded index` or other errors.

```
@forelse($notifications as $n)
    @php
        $data = $n->data;
    @endphp
    {!! var_dump($data) !!}
@empty
    nothing
@endforelse
```

### edit

When I try to `json_decode` the data, it tells me, it is an array:

```
{!! var_dump(json_decode($data)) !!}

json_decode() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given
```

`print_r()` says the same:

```
{!! print_r($data) !!}

Array ( [message] => New comment from pp on one of your photos. [action] => /photos/9372 ) 1
```

`var_dump()` says it is an array:

```
{!! var_dump($data) !!}

array(2) { ["message"]=> string(42) "New comment from pp on one of your photos." ["action"]=> string(12) "/photos/9372" }
```

But when I want to display a certain value, it does not work:

```
{!! $data["message"] !!}

Undefined index: message
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you are looping through the array of notifications when you attempt to access the message part of the array:

```
@foreach ($notifications as $notification)
    {{ $notification->data['message'] }}
@endforeach
```